# How to close FullTrustProcess from UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, process

I have a UWP app that launches a FullTrustProcess when the UWP app is closed:

MainPage.xaml.cs (UWP App):

```
private async void HandleSystemNavigationManagerCloseRequested(object sender, SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs e)
{
    if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
    {
        await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
    }
}
```

When the process is running, you can right-click the Systray icon and Open the UWP app again. The process is then closed when the UWP app is running again:

```
private async void OpenUWPApp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Launch the UWP app:
    var appListEntries = await Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync();
    await appListEntries.First().LaunchAsync();

    // Close the process:
    Application.Exit();
}
```

The problem is, if the user closes the UWP app, and the FullTrustProcess app is launched, and then the UWP app is opened again by double clicking the UWP app icon on the desktop, then the UWP app launches again but the FullTrustProcess app is still running after being launched from the previous UWP session.

**So I am needing to know how to check (from the UWP app) if the FullTrustProcess app is running, and if so, to close it. As I only want either the UWP app running, or the FullTrustProcess running, but not both at the same time.**

I was thinking about using the AppServiceConnection to send a message to the process from the UWP app, but the Connection is only established after the UWP app is closed, so in the new UWP app session, the Connection is null when it launches.

App.xaml.cs (UWP App):

```
public static AppServiceConnection Connection = null;

protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
    
    if (args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails is AppServiceTriggerDetails details)
    {
        AppServiceDeferral = args.TaskInstance.GetDeferral();
        args.TaskInstance.Canceled += OnTaskCanceled;
        Connection = details.AppServiceConnection;
        Connection.RequestReceived += HandleSystemTrayConnectionRequestReceived;
        Connection.ServiceClosed += HandleSystemTrayConnectionServiceClosed;
    }
}
```

For reference, this is the guide I followed: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am needing to know how to check (from the UWP app) if the FullTrustProcess app is running, and if so, to close it. As I only want either the UWP app running, or the FullTrustProcess running, but not both at the same time.

First, it is not possible to close other process from UWP apps since UWP apps are running in the sandbox which meant UWP apps are limited to access the system resource. And UWP apps are also not able to detect if another process is running because [Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0) is not supported in UWP apps.

So the solution is to do the job in the full trust process that launched from the UWP app. You could use [Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0) in the full trust process to detect if the UWP app is running. If it is running, then call  `Application.Exit();` to close itself.